# С какой версии android доступен Snackbars?

Tags: java, android, material-design

На устройствах android 5.1 довольно часто вылезают ошибки, связанные со Snackbars.

В документации указана версия support-library (22.2.0), но с какой версии android начинает работать Snackbars?

Answer (score 0):

Android 5.0 Lollipop — один из самых значимых релизов системы Android , в немалой степени благодаря введению концепции Material Design, нового языка дизайна, который преобразил Android.   Подробные спецификации  помогают начать использовать  Material Design, но не решают проблемы разработчиков, связанные с обеспечением обратной совместимости приложений.

Новая библиотека поддержки  Android Design Support Library  делает доступным весь набор компонентов материального дизайна для всех версий, начиная с Android 2.1 и выше:

Navigation View (для Navigation Drawer) — панель навигации
Floating Labels (для EditText) — плавающий ярлык
Floating Action Button (FAB) плавающая кнопка
Snackbar — всплывающее уведомление с кнопкой
Tabs — вкладки
Motion and Scroll framework — управление жестами и прокруткой